# Error running test kotlin multiplatform. kotlinx-coroutines-test for js with Error: Fail to fetch

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I am using the workaround for testing coroutines in common code. the most suggested workaround and seems to work for a lot of people [kotlinx-coroutines-test for multiplatform](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1996), but by js test is failing.Any idea why it is failing or if anybody faced this issue?
or am I doing something wrong?

running for JVM the test passes but failed for the js with an error

```
Error: Fail to fetch
Error: Fail to fetch
    at Object.captureStack(/Users/ipkiss/code/Multiplatform-sample-project/build/js/node_modules/kotlin/kotlin/builtins.kt:103)
    at <global>.new Error(/Users/ipkiss/code/Multiplatform-sample-project/build/js/packages/Multiplatform-sample-project-test/adapter-browser.js:71220)
    at <global>.<unknown>(/Users/ipkiss/code/Multiplatform-sample-project/build/js/node_modules/ktor-ktor-client-core-jsLegacy/ktor-ktor-client-core-jsLegacy.js:179408)
```

the runBlockingTest is implemented as follows for JS from the above example

```
//expected
expect fun runBlockingTest(block: suspend () -> Unit)
expect val testCoroutineContext: CoroutineContext

//actual
val testScope = MainScope()
actual val testCoroutineContext: CoroutineContext = testScope.coroutineContext
actual fun runBlockingTest(block: suspend () -> Unit): dynamic = testScope.promise { block() }
```

my test looks like this

```
    @Test
    fun should_make_http_call() = runBlockingTest {
        val response = HttpCall.request("https://stackoverflow.com/")
        assertTrue { response.contains("Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn") }
    }
```

and here this is what my dependencies.

```
val ktor_version = "1.5.1"
val kotlin_version = "1.4.0"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnit()
        }
    }
    js(LEGACY) {
        browser {
            testTask {
                useKarma {
                    useChromeHeadless()
                    webpackConfig.cssSupport.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:$kotlin_version")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:$kotlin_version")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2")

        }
    }
    val commonTest by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
            implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
        }
    }
    val jvmMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version")
        }
    }
    val jvmTest by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
            implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.2")
        }
    }
    val jsMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-js:$ktor_version")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2")
        }
    }
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
    }
```